# How can I create OpenCV framework?

Tags: xcode, macos, frameworks, opencv

I use OpenCV library in my Mac creating programs and compiling it with Terminal and makefiles.
It's so easy install opencv using macports and create a generic makefile to build your project.

I want to use this library with Xcode to create a app for my mac and think create a OpenCV framework is the best way.

I read this entry to compile it with Xcode but i don't know how to continue to create a framework. [link](http://computer-vision-talks.com/2010/12/building-opencv-for-ios/)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

if you just want to use (and don't insist on compiling it yourself...) someone already made a framework out of opencv:

http://www.ient.rwth-aachen.de/cms/software/opencv/

Also helpful might be:

http://stefanix.net/opencv-in-xcode

Hope this helps!