# dlib Displaying values on the screen

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, dlib

I encountered a strange error- whenever I'm including `#include <dlib/gui_widgets.h>`
to my projects and declaring a variable (for example `dlib::image_window win`) following errors appear:

`'DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT is defined so you can't use the GUI code.  Turn DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT off if you want to use it.'` and `'Also make sure you have libx11-dev installed on your system'` (from guy_core_kernel_2.h). I was searching and found some suggestions that the cmake of dlib could fail- but I really doubt so, I'm already doing a detection of landmarks.

The reason why I'm trying to include and declare one of the widgets is displaying values on the screen (there is no equivalent of opencv `putText()`, is there?.

I would be very grateful for any help. :)

Comment: Do you have libx11-dev installed? Are you able to compile and run dlib's examples? Do you need to display via dlib or opencv is acceptable too?

Comment: Yes, I installed X11 and successfully ran the samples. I thought about using opencv as a support to print things on the screen but wanted to make sure it is not possible using dlib. :)

Comment: Samples building process is slightly different from using installed dlib. You have three ways to run dlib: 1 - re-build dlib and ensure you have GUI support (mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && cmake --build . --traget install) - check building messages for GUI support enabled 2 - use code from CMakeLists.txt in examples folder and include it in your project 3- include dlib/all/source.cpp into your project

Comment: What I should have added- I already used features of dlib in my project. Everything builds and runs perfectly, but I am unable to use any of the widgets. I built the lib using instructions from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591254/how-to-build-dlib-for-ios/35058969#35058969

Do you think using `cmake --build . --target install` instead of `cmake --build . --config Release` will change anything? I am getting the error: `make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop`

Comment: Additionally I don;t think I can include the .cpp file in my project- it has mostly swift files with .mm wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I decided to use covertion from `dlib::array2d` to `cv::Matrix`  (`dlib::toMat(dlib::array2d)` function) and use `cv::putText()` (as mentioned previousely). It turned out the Xcode didn't properly linked libraries from openCV- helpful were the following links: [How can I create OpenCV framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223742/how-can-i-create-opencv-framework)

and

http://blogs.wcode.org/2014/11/howto-setup-xcode-6-1-to-work-with-opencv-libraries/

Also if someone can't find Frameworks in Library:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4195808?tstart=0